# Visual Studio 2017 - how to point debug symbols for diagsession generated on the other machine

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017. I open diagsession file generated on other machine. Output window shows that symbols have not been loaded, for example:

```
Symbols failed to load for C:\Workspace\App\libA.dll. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

I have built appropriate libs. The libs have been build from the same source code as on the other machine. Then I have set a path to the pdb files: Debug/Options/Symbols/Symbol file (.pdb) locations. It doesn't help. I have also copied libs and pdbs to the some location as mentioned in the output output window, i.e. Symbols failed to load for... but it also doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong ? How to point symbols for diagsession generated on the other machine ?